# POST with HTTPClient

Tags: java, httpclient

So I have Apache HTTPClient v.4.5. I want to post the username and password (e.g. "tes","ted"). I have not found any example on how to do this. Is it because they are old? Did I install incorrectly? I want to write my own program, but I can't even get a "hello world" done, even with others code.

Does anyone have an example that works?

Comment: There are examples in the [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) - check out 1.1 and 1.1.7.1.

Comment: How should we know? You haven't provided anything actually useful, like, say... SOURCE CODE.

Comment: I think before trying to use HTTPClient, you should do some research about the HTTP protocol, and what browsers send exactly when they send out a form. After you understand that, you'll be able to implement it using any client.

Comment: well its kind of hard to have code if nothing works...

Comment: In general, if you've made an attempt, you can (and should) include your non-working code in your question along with any error messages you're getting at compile time or run time. It's much easier for people to help find and correct errors to guide you to a working solution than to give you an entire working solution from scratch. (And it also shows that you've put effort into solving the problem yourself.)